# Having Trouble Devloping Minecraft Plugin

Tags: java, minecraft

Following a YouTube Tutorial but when I run the plugin Minecraft doesn't register it at all.
The plugin is meant to return "Hi!" when the play does /hello or /hi.
When I put the plugin on my server nothing, doesn't even register in /plugins

**Code:
Main.java:**

```
package me.Cheese_Echidna.helloworld;

import me.Cheese_Echidna.helloworld.commands.HelloCommand;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        new HelloCommand(this);

    }
}
```

**HelloCommand.java:**

```
package me.Cheese_Echidna.helloworld.commands;

import me.Cheese_Echidna.helloworld.Main;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;


public class HelloCommand implements CommandExecutor {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Main plugin;

    public HelloCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("hello").setExecutor(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
         if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
             sender.sendMessage("Only players may execute this command!");
             return true;
         }
         Player p = (Player) sender;

         if (p.hasPermission("hello.use")) {
             p.sendMessage("Hi!");

             return true;
         } else {
             p.sendMessage("You do not have permission to execute this command!");
         }

        return false;
    }

}
```

**plugin.yml:**

```
name: HelloWorld
version: 1.0
author: Cheese_Echidna
main: me.Cheese_Echidna.helloworld.main
description: My first Bukkit plugin

commands:
  hello:
   aliases: [hi]
   description: This is the hello command!
```

The YT tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XaU8JKQW0Ao

I have attached a photo of the file structure here:
[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you building the `.jar` file in any way? What do you do after you've written the code? How are you putting it on your server?

Comment: I'm just exporting to .jar

Comment: Hello! Could you please post the ouput of the server console upon start?

Answer (score 0):

I have a basic question.
Have you installed the Vanilla Minecraft version on your Minecraft server? To use Bukkit or Spigot plugins you have to use **their extensions**.

Answer (score 0):

I´m not shure. But the problem might be in the plugin.yml!

first its important that you use exactly one space for tabs in the plugin.yml

than another problem is that you have the path behind main: has to lead to a class
in this case it would be
main: me.Cheese_Echidna.helloworld.main.Main

The corrected plugin.yml should look like this:

```
name: HelloWorld
version: 1.0
author: Cheese_Echidna
main: me.Cheese_Echidna.helloworld.main.Main
description: My first Bukkit plugin

commands:
 hello:
  aliases: [hi]
  description: This is the hello command!
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the API version in your plugin.yml. Very common mistake, don't worry, a lot of people do this. Here's the plugin.yml wiki for more info: [Plugin.yml wiki](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/plugin-yml/#:%7E:text=The%20plugin.,All%20attributes%20are%20case%20sensitive.)

It's also supposed to look like this. It seems you have the files in folders, not packages.

[My plugin.yml for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqflS.png)